# Notebook won't boot properly and SSD disappeared

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd, freeze, lenovo-laptop

I bought a Lenovo ideapad U410 a while ago. It had a 20 GB SSD in addition to the 500 GB HDD.

Someday it miraculously stopped booting properly. The Lenovo screen showed up for minutes. And the only way to make it boot was to wait for an arbitrary amount of minutes and then press ctrl+alt+del to make it reboot.

I tried to reinstall Windows. But for some reason the SSD won't show up again. And the problem persisted.
I even tried to install different versions of Windows AND Linux (mostly ubuntu), but neither did the SSD ever show up again (not even in partition managers), nor did this boot error disappear.

Has anyone an explanation for any of this?

Comment: My guess would be that your SSD drive is dead/dying.  Test it in another computer.

Comment: @Techie007 it's a built-in SSD in an ultrabook. I cannot easily get it out. Also I don't have another machine I could try it on :/

Comment: See if the SSD manufacturer has any ssd fitness test software to download and use.

Comment: Its fairly easy to remove-replace the ssd in that model..http://www.alphadevx.com/a/398-Replacing-the-MSATA-SSD-in-a-Lenovo-U410

Answer (score 0):

You need to check to see if the computer "sees" the hard drive. In Windows 10, Hold down the windows key and the X key simultaneously, then choose disk management. If the resulting windows does not show you the ssd, then it is damaged and must be replaced.

Comment: Your answer is not really an answer it's a comment. You are assuming he's using Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

SSD is only mounted for Caching. The system could technically run without it.

As this is a very low capacity SSD i am sure you can find them very cheap, my recommendation would be to replace it and even possibly upgrade it to higher capacity.

These days you can get 500GB SSD for around $100

Following are few links you might find useful

https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-U-and-S-Series-Notebooks/Lenovo-U410-32GB-SSD-Failed/td-p/1524904

[Ideapad U410 SSD problem](http://www.wisumpire.com/ideapad-u410-ssd-problem/)

[Replacing the MSATA SSD in a Lenovo U410](http://www.alphadevx.com/a/398-Replacing-the-MSATA-SSD-in-a-Lenovo-U410)